# No auth_token, userId in the $_REQUEST['signed_request']

Tags: php, facebook

Why facebook returns me the Signed Request ($_REQUEST['signed_request']) without userId and oauth_token fields?
when i decode the signed request this is what i have:

```
Array ( 
         [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
         [issued_at] => 1365781115     
         [user] => Array ( 
                           [country] => ar 
                           [locale] => es_LA 
                           [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 )
                          ) 
     )
```

where are the user_id and oauth_token fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields that you are getting are the default fields. Signed request contains the field `user_id` and `oauth_token` only when the User has logged into your application or has authorized your application earlier.
For detail on the fields available in **signed_request** check the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the signed request at first. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/)

Or try this:

```
//save signed request for decoding
$srq = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];

function parse_signed_request($srq) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $srq, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);
  $GLOBALS['sdata'] = $data;//set a superglobal for later use
  return ($data);
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return (base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/')));
}

//call the signer req. decode
parse_signed_request($srq);
```

And the info UID and Token is available this way:

```
$sdata['oauth_token'];
$sdata['user_id'];
```

This is what i use, not the cleanest probably with the super global, but hey I'm newbie at PHP.